# What is the right SQL statement to INSERT or UPDATE record in this code

Tags: sql, ms-access, asp-classic, vbscript

I have this code for add Production data. Since now I have implement inventory module, I start to embed qty update function to every related modules by the help of this SO member. Now it comes to production module that quite complicate because this function must select whether to use INSERT or UPDATE sql to do proper work, which I've tried but failed to make it work. So could you please suggest me with my edited code. Thank you very much.

Below is my edited code that fail: 
It can use "UPDATE" but fail when use "INSERT" SQL

```
<%

    pd_id = Request.form("pd_id")

    pdtn_st_date =   Request.form("pdtn_st_date")   
    pdtn_st_note =   Request.form("pdtn_st_note")   
    pdtn_st_pdNote = Request.form("pdtn_st_pdNote")

    qty_fabric_used =   Request.form("qty_fabric_used") 
        if qty_fabric_used <> "" then
            qty_fabric_used = YardToCm(qty_fabric_used)
        else
            qty_fabric_used = 0
        end if

    unit_per_fb = Request.form("unit_per_fb")
        if unit_per_fb = "" then
            unit_per_fb = 0
        end if

    is_finished = Request.form("is_finished")       
        if is_finished <> "" then
            is_finished = True
        else
            is_finished = False
        end if      

    fb_sheet = Request.Form("fb_sheet")
        if fb_sheet = "" then
            fb_sheet = 0
        end if 
    fb_width = Request.Form("fb_width")
        if fb_width = "" then
            fb_width = 0
        end if

    edit_pdtn_startup = Request.form("edit_pdtn_startup")

    pdtn_st_qty_act_dz = Request.form("pdtn_st_qty_act")
        if pdtn_st_qty_act_dz <> "." then
            pdtn_st_qty_act = DztoPcs(pdtn_st_qty_act_dz)
        end if      

'<---------------  Update qty to Inventory table here ------->
Dim con 
Dim rsInventory 

set con=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
con.Provider="Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
con.Open(Server.Mappath("../database/tkp.mdb"))

        Set rsInventory = con.Execute("SELECT * FROM tbl_inventory WHERE pd_id = '" & pd_id & "'" )             
        if rsInventory.EOF then
            con.Execute("INSERT INTO tbl_inventory (inv_qty_act, inv_date, pd_id) VALUES (inv_qty_act + " & pdtn_st_qty_act & ", date() ,'" & pd_id & "'"  )
'           con.Execute("INSERT INTO tbl_inventory ( pd_id) VALUES ( '" & pd_id & "'")
        else

            con.Execute("UPDATE tbl_inventory SET inv_qty_act = inv_qty_act + " & pdtn_st_qty_act & ", inv_date = date() WHERE pd_id = '" & pd_id & "'"  ) 
        end if          

'<---------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->

    call checkBlank(pd_id)

    if SomethingError <> "yes" then

        Call DBConnOpen()

            Set Rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
            Set Rs.ActiveConnection = Conn

            strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tbl_pdtn_startup"
            if edit_pdtn_startup = "Y" then         
                pdtn_st_id = Request.form("pdtn_st_id")
                strSQL = strSQL & " WHERE pdtn_st_id =" & pdtn_st_id & ""
                Rs.Open strSQL, Conn, 1, 3      

            pdtn_st_qty_act_dz = Request.form("pdtn_st_qty_act")
                if pdtn_st_qty_act_dz <> "." then
                    pdtn_st_qty_act = DztoPcs(pdtn_st_qty_act_dz)
                end if  

            end if

            if edit_pdtn_startup <> "Y" then    
            Rs.Open strSQL, Conn, 1, 3
            Rs.AddNew   

            end if

            Rs.Fields("pdtn_st_date") = pdtn_st_date
            Rs.Fields("pdtn_st_note") = pdtn_st_note
            Rs.Fields("pd_id") = pd_id  
            Rs.Fields("pdtn_st_pdNote") = pdtn_st_pdNote
            Rs.Fields("pdtn_st_qty_act") = pdtn_st_qty_act
            Rs.Fields("qty_fabric_used") = qty_fabric_used
            Rs.Fields("unit_per_fb") = unit_per_fb
            Rs.Fields("is_finished") = is_finished  
            Rs.Fields("fb_width") = fb_width
            Rs.fields("fb_sheet") = fb_sheet            

            Rs.Update
            Rs.Close

        if edit_pdtn_startup = "Y" then
            response.redirect "production_view.asp?pdtn_st_id=" & pdtn_st_id
        else
            strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tbl_pdtn_startup order by pdtn_st_id desc"
            Rs.Open strSQL, Conn, 1, 3
            latest_id = Rs("pdtn_st_id")
            Rs.close
            response.redirect "production_addSzCl.asp?pdtn_st_id=" & latest_id
        end if

        Call DBConnClose()
    else
        call writeInputError
    end if

session("pdtn_st_id") = pdtn_st_id 
%>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closing bracket is missing in value list. That may be one problem. Also inv_qty_act should not be in value list.

```
con.Execute("INSERT INTO tbl_inventory (inv_qty_act, inv_date, pd_id) VALUES (inv_qty_act + " & pdtn_st_qty_act & ", date() ,'" & pd_id & "'"  )
```

Should be corrected as following

```
con.Execute("INSERT INTO tbl_inventory (inv_qty_act, inv_date, pd_id) VALUES (" & pdtn_st_qty_act & ", date() ,'" & pd_id & "')" )
```